# solr sort results by geometry (nearest on top)

Tags: solr, solrj

I am trying to execute query

```
http://192.168.1.101:8080/solr/locationList_shard3_replica2/select?q=*%3A*&fq=area%3A%5Csang*&wt=json&indent=true&fl:_dist_:geodist(geometry,19.4349,75.6909)
```

It need results near by 9.4349,75.6909 on top but above query fails.

Is their another way to boost nearest results?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of solr spatial search,

> geodist is a distance function that takes three optional parameters: (sfield,latitude,longitude). You can use the geodist function to sort results by distance or score return results.
>   For example, to sort your results by ascending distance, enter ...&q=*:*&fq={!geofilt}&sfield=store&pt=45.15,-93.85&d=50&sort=geodist() asc.

So in your case, you can query like

```
&q=*:*&fq={!geofilt}&sfield=geometry&pt=45.15,-93.85&d=50&sort=geodist()
```

where d is the radial distance under which you want your results to be in. For more info,refer to : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spatial+Search